# Folder has disappeared after gitignore

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, git, visual-studio, github

I and my teammates are working in a MVC C# proyect using Visual Studio. Today I've tried to do a .gitignore to ignore folders to be commited to our repository and a folder (`App_Data/`) has disappeared (in our repository).
I'll explain the step by step I've done:

1. I made my .gitignore:

```bash
Tp_Integrador/.vs/
Tp_Integrador/Tp_Integrador/obj/
Tp_Integrador/packages/
Tp_Integrador/Tp_Integrador/App_Data/
Tp_Integrador/Tp_Integrador/bin/
Tp_Integrador/Tp_Integrador/Content/
Tp_Integrador/Tp_Integrador/Properties/
Tp_Integrador/Tp_Integrador/Scripts/
```

2. `git add .` , `git commit -m "asdfad"` and `git push`
3. `git rm -r --cached .` , `git add .` and `git commit -m "Cached"`
4. Finally, in our repository I don't see our folder `App_Data/` and in VisualStudio i see `App_Data/` empty and some `.cs` (C# Classes) untrackable because a teammate has made changes and I didn't see them.

Comment: Was there anything in `App_Data` besides the `Tp_Integrador/Tp_Integrador/bin/` folder?

Comment: I would think that what's going on is that for git directories that have no files tracked by it, it just "deletes" them (at least in terms of the tree object that is saved inside git's DB.

Comment: @maccettura they are different folders. There is a white space between each pair of folders :(

Comment: Well then I am really confused, if they are two different items than `Tp_Integrador/Tp_Integrador/App_Data/` is the reason its not showing up.  You are literally ignoring it

Comment: Yes, but it has been deleted from the repository

Comment: @AgustinMeinardo Right, _because you have ignored it_.

Comment: Git can't have empty folders. So if you're ignoring the contents, you're basically ignoring the folder as far as Git is concerned. You could get around this by putting a dummy file in there, and ignoring all the files in App_Data *except* your dummy file. Of course, I think the bigger question is: what are you using App_Data for? What kind of shared state are you putting in there?

Comment: Sincerely, i have no idea. App_Data content change when we change the code (for example, a C# class). What i want is to return in time and have the folders as yesterday

Comment: Well you need to figure out exactly what you're doing with it, because you may find out you don't need it at all.

Answer (score 1):

Git does not store empty folders, so if you want to have the `App_Data` folder there, you'll have to manually create it again (if you deleted it) and put an empty file inside, that Git can track and make sure the folder always gets created.

A common pattern is to create an empty file with the name `.gitkeep` inside the folders that you always want Git to keep, and then inside your `.gitignore`, you tell Git to ignore your folder, alright, but not to ignore files that are named `.gitkeep` (anywhere).

e.g.

```
Tp_Integrador/Tp_Integrador/App_Data/
!.gitkeep
```

Answer (score 0):

> App_Data content change when we change the code (for example, a C# class). What i want is to return in time and have the folders as yesterday

If you can, reset your branch to the commit before your sequence described in your question: do `git log`, and pick the commit before the one with "Cached" as a comment.

```
git checkout -b newBranch <oldCommit>
git push -u origin newBranch
```

The goal is to report your changes to that `newBranch` before making it replace the old one.

Then, if you need to ignore some parts of `Tp_Integrador/Tp_Integrador`, but not a subfolder, do in your `.gitignore` (in `newBranch`):

```
Tp_Integrador/Tp_Integrador/**
!Tp_Integrador/Tp_Integrador/**/
!Tp_Integrador/Tp_Integrador/App_data/
```

That way, `git rm -r --cached . , git add .` will add files from `Tp_Integrador/Tp_Integrador/App_data/`, but not from any other subfolder of `Tp_Integrador/Tp_Integrador/`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I reset my branch and made a new repository starting with the last state.